# Help - Atmega328p, converting a PWM servo code from pin9 to pin6

Tags: servo, pwm, avr

I found a working code that uses pin9 (PB1) on my Arduino for controlling a Servo, but in my project, an ultrasonic sensor is already using that pin/timer. I want to convert the code to use pin6 (PD6), changed the registers according to the atmega's datasheet, but it doesn't work. Need help :/

The code should allow me to turn a servo using a potentiometer.

```cpp
#define F_CPU 16000000 //16MHz
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PWM_PRESCALLER 64
#define ICR_MAX (long double)F_CPU/PWM_PRESCALLER/50
#define OCR_MIN (float)ICR_MAX/37.5 // /8.75
#define OCR_MAX (float)ICR_MAX/8.7 // 37.5

volatile unsigned long adc_val=0;
volatile unsigned long counter=0;
unsigned long curr_adc=0;

ISR (ADC_vect)
{
adc_val += ADC;
counter++;
}

int main(void)
{
    DDRD |= (1<<DDD6);
    ICR1 = ICR_MAX;
    OCR0A = OCR_MIN;
    TCCR0A = (1 << COM1A1) | (1<<WGM00) | (1<<WGM01);
    TCCR0B = (1<<WGM02) | (1<<CS01) | (1<<CS00);
    ADMUX = (1 << REFS0);
    ADCSRA = (1 << ADEN)|(1 << ADATE)|(1 << ADIE)|(1<<ADPS2)|(1<<ADPS1)|(1<<ADPS0);

    sei();
    ADCSRA |= (1<<ADSC);

    while(1)
    {
        if(counter >= 1000)
        {
            cli();
            unsigned long round_val = round(adc_val / counter);
            adc_val=0;
            counter=0;
            if(abs(round_val - curr_adc) > 1)
            {
                curr_adc = round_val; 
            }
            long double ocr = OCR_MIN + ((long double)curr_adc * (OCR_MAX - OCR_MIN)/1024);

            OCR0A = (int)round(ocr);
            sei();
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and try pasting the code again. Somehow there are extra newlines and all indentation was removed, making the code pretty hard to read.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a *lot* simpler to just do an `analogRead` each time through your loop? And use the [Servo library](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/servo) to control the servo?

Answer (score 1):

PORTB bit 6 is controlled with TIMER0 while PORTB bit 1 is controlled with TIMER1.  Therefore you need to change the timer variables appropriately.  One mistake in your code is that you leave ICR1.  It should be OCRA if you want to use TIMER0.

Comment: I thought of ICR0, but according to the datasheet, there is no ICR0.

Comment: Checked that, you are right.  I think you can only use OCRA.  Not OCR0A?

Comment: No OCRA according to Atmel studio

Comment: Timer0 is already used for delay and millis. Use pin 3 or 11, as those use timer2 which isn't used.

Comment: My problem is now that I have to use ICR0 for my servo and ultrasonic sensor and then they get confused. Is there an alternative for this ICR0?

Comment: I think you will solve it by reading the data sheet.  Values for TCCR0A and TCCR0B are determined by the waveform generation mode, value of TOP and clock prescaler.  According to your code, WGM=0x7 i.e. fast PWM, OCR0A=TOP.  Read section 19.7.3 of Atmel-42735B-ATmega328/P_Datasheet_Complete-11/2016

Answer (score -1):

I agree with [Nick Gammon](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/10794/nick-gammon)'s comment that it is a lot easier using the Arduino Platform and use [`AnalogRead()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/analog-io/analogread/) function in conjunction with the [servo library](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/servo).

Having said that, you have chosen to write the program from scratch as many others prefer to do for one reason or another. I wanted to pass on the 2 web pages that I always go to when I am playing with the PWM frequencies and setup.

- http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/TimerPWMCheatsheet
- https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SecretsOfArduinoPWM